# Is there equivalent of BatchMerge in jOOQ version 3.13.4?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I need to do upsert on batch records.
I'm using jOOQ version 3.13.4, and I cannot update to the latest jOOQ version because I'm using Java 8. If I update the jOOQ version, then I get java.util.concurrent.flow not found errors with the current Java version. I have other constraints due to which I cannot update the Java version of my Spring Boot Application.

Is there a workaround for batchUpsert/batchMerge in jOOQ 3.13.4?

Comment: The commercial editions of jOOQ 3.16 still support Java 8, see: https://www.jooq.org/download/versions

Answer (score 1):

```
 postgresql.loadInto(tableName).batchAll() // Batch Upsert Operation
                .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
                .loadRecords(list)
                .fields(tableName.fields())
                .execute();
```